# PipEnv's Pipfile sections

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

I am researching Pipenv's Pipfile and its sections. More specifically, the requires section. Sadly I cannot find any information about it outside the specification of the Python version. Is there someone who can send me some documentation about it or explain to me if this is the only use of that section? I highly doubt that it is a single purpose.

As far as I know:

1. The source section is for the location you want to install packages from.
2. Packages section is for packages used on dev and prod.
3. Dec-packages is for packages that are strictly used on dev.
4. Scripts section is for defining aliases that the developer can use in the virtual environment.
5. Requires is for the python version and ?
6. There are no other sections.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You're right, the documentation is pretty sparse. It may be more helpful if you specify what you are trying to accomplish. If you have specific questions regarding the Pipfile format, it would probably be best to ask the devs over on github.

Comment: Thank you, @AaronCiuffo, but my question is in general. I do not know what to expect, and that is why I am researching the matter. Thank you for the idea about GitHub.